# Why does my badge count fluctuate?

Tags: support, badges

My badge count drops from 4 to 1 and then goes back up after an intermittent amount of time. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Is it fluctuating between your [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159498/garrann) profile and your [main SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1159498/garrann) profile?

Comment: [Oscillation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166483/165773)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Badges on the main site and meta are calculated separately.  So this is not a bug, but the intended behavior.

[On the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159498/garrann?tab=badges), you have 4 badges.  [On meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159498/garrann?tab=badges) you have 1.  That's the fluctuation you are seeing.

Comment: And now OP has 3 for asking a good question.

Comment: Make that eleven.

Comment: He has eleven reputation, but only 4 badges

Comment: Now 6 badges on main and 4 on meta. This answer will need a lot of editing to stay current. :P