# If Stack Overflow is so highly reputation-motivated, why do people bother coming to Meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've come to believe over my relatively passive life on Stack Overflow that it is, unfortunately, heavily reputation focused rather than solution and help-based.

That being said, since Meta does not provide any sort of recognition that is sought after on this site (aside from watching your upvotes), why do people even bother contributing here?

Comment: Because they want to make the site better? Internet points isn't the only motivation people have for contributing to SO, and for those whom it is the primary motivation, they're often missing the point of the site.

Comment: That's literally what we all hope, but the harsh reality is that people really only care about their reputation. It's kind of rampant and obvious. There are obviously the exceptions; maybe those are who we find on Meta.

Comment: Not everyone is motivated by reputation. I was at one time, but now reputation is useless to me, my motivation from using the site has moved from reputation to helping people, and improving the site in the name of making it more useful/higher quality goes toward that goal.

Comment: I come for the drama.  And the popcorn is pretty good, too.

Comment: I think that's untrue. The great majority of *my* time on SO (and here on meta) has been involved in tasks that generate no reputation.

Comment: @Shiri You're quite right that there are some people who come to SO primarily to earn rep, rather than for any other reason.  Those people tend to not be active meta contributors.  Just because *some* people are only here for the rep doesn't mean *all* people are here only for the rep.  And isn't not like there's 100% participation in meta; not even close.

Comment: I pose this question I guess solely because I lack faith in the genuineness of people and that the population of people that actually _do_ want to help is relatively scarce. I guess coming to Meta, where naturally people _are_ going to care more about the site to ask why people don't care is kind of contradictory.

Comment: Entertainment​​

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? I understand that people might disagree with the premise or the conclusion, but this is a perfectly valid question nonetheless.

Comment: Deadly serious reply: I go to SO to get answers (and comment/answer/edit). I go to meta to actually learn something. And I learn something new, every day.

Comment: @Pablo voting on meta works differently. Generally a downvote means "don't agree" or "don't want", depending on the context. It has nothing to do with the quality of the question.

Comment: @Gimby Oh, I see. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @Pablo here's a second tidbit: you don't lose anything for being downvoted on meta. So feel free to confirm/learn that something you think or do is unpopular :) Better here than on SO itself.

Comment: As a user with only 344 rep, I have actually hit a funny situation: I have _zero_ desire to go and fight for reputation, yet the strong desire to help improve the site. The situation comes from the need for large amounts of reputation for me to be able to help more on the site. I settle for editing, flagging, and helping out on Meta. :)

Comment: That's nice to know. I always end up here from SOs sidebar so I thought similar rules applied. I'm gonna read the FAQ right now. Thanks!

Comment: [Because Meta](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/bb/bbc0561e7669f725b4a1ac51fad18c5eed76fc9050b3ba93334a97d1cf5df451.jpg)

Comment: Notable how the users that claim they visit for the drama and entertainment have deleted their accounts.  Just as there was lots of drama.  So that was just BS, you do have to care at least a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes you guys improve this board so much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305524/what-makes-you-guys-improve-this-board-so-much)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Stack Overflow is...a complicated beast.

There are a lot of rules to it - both spoken and unspoken; a lot of nuance, style, innuendo, and truckloads of community-centric issues that crop up every so often.

Someone that just shows up to Stack Overflow probably doesn't understand a lot of that, and will *easily* get buried by the norms of the site.  Here on Meta, we're given a chance to discuss (via [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)) and challenge the norms, as well as clarify how we should be helping out around here.

In fact, many of the policies that are in effect today - notably, the removal of meta tags like "homework", how we deal with questions which are off-topic, and how [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) are dealt with - were forged here.  This helps users who have a few more privileges to deal with questions understand how to deal with them better, as well as gives users a place to ask about their [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) or [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) to see if it falls in scope.

It's also the place where reporting a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) for the site is allowed.  If you *do* encounter bugs, *please* do report them - we don't want to use a buggy site, and most of us do get agitated when we see programming bugs since, well, we're all programmers, and we know what it's like to have a bug escape into production.

Remember when I said you could challenge the norms?  In part, that's what [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is for; we can suggest changes to the site or the way a certain feature behaves with this tag.  It offers us a lot of power, but even then it's subject to what the company needs to focus on most.

You **really** don't bother coming to Meta because you're interested in internet points.  You bother coming to Meta because you're interested in Stack Overflow and its inner workings.  I should also say that users *should* come to Meta as well, just to keep up with how the site works.

Comment: Awesome answer dude. +10000 for context. I learnt a lot.

Comment: I fully agree with this answer when the group of "people" described in it is named specifically the group of people who want to do the right thing. For people who just come to SO to get easy answers and solutions to any and all questions / problems / homework assignments /etc., SO is actually quite uncomplicated if you ask me. Either you do right and you get your answers, or you do wrong and you get a very fast and direct refusal response to it.

Answer (score 19):

There are indeed lots of people who come to SO because they're highly motivated by the reputation.

There are also lots of people who are here for other reasons, whether it be to learn, to create quality repositories of knowledge, because they enjoy it, etc.

(Of course, in reality most people have some combination of different motivators, not just one of these.)

The people you see on meta are largely those in the second camp, rather than the first.

Comment: And that's why I don't trust low-rep people on Meta, nor politicians who never had a real job. You _have_ to get your hands dirty to know what people are talking about.

Comment: @CodeCaster Out of curiosity, how much rep do I need on main to earn the ability to gain trust?

Comment: @TZHX 600k of course.

Comment: @TZHK of course I have no preset limit, but it's more like: if you want me to take you seriously if you're telling us how to do certain things, I want to see in your profile that you have done those things. Practice what you preach, so to say.

Comment: @TZHX It's also not strictly boolean.  It's not like you go from complete mistrust to full trust when you cross a line.  The degree to which you trust someone is proportional to their level of experience.

Answer (score 11):

> why do people bother coming to SO Meta?

The drama.

There's people who don't believe the rules apply to them and want their question reopened because they desperately need an answer, there's people who think they can change the world with one post on Meta, there's questions about the most minor changes on the website (which I read to confirm that I didn't go crazy when I feel like the font has been increased by .01 em), and so on.

But in general, I read Meta posts to confirm that how I interpret the rules is still valid, as often there are discussions about how other people read them.

It's a nice way to pass the time.

Answer (score 9):

> SO Meta does not provide any sort of recognition

That's actually not true.  Your [meta profile earns separate badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300067/why-does-my-badge-count-fluctuate) from the main profile.  Additionally, you main profile shows off your "Top meta posts" for others to see.

> why do people even bother contributing to Meta

- They want to improve the site ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request))
- They want to learn how to better use the site ([support](/questions/tagged/support)) or learn more about site culture for issue like voting and moderation ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)).
- It's fun.  Meta is a silly place that tolerates puns (see almost any [bunination-request](/questions/tagged/bunination-request)).  It's a place to interact more with people than with answers and code.

Answer (score -8):

Because they care about improving this site.

Comment: Maybe, but you need to define *site*. I'm not mainly here to report bugs, so it is not that kind of improvement ...