# Deletion of an answered question

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011309/default-value-of-dropdownlist-in-an-html-beginform-block) today. I organized the body of the question: provided the central question, a concise context, and code examples. I summarized what I had done so far.

I got an answer. I thought things went all right.

I come back this afternoon and found my question got downvoted into the negative zone. When there is a downvote without any comment, it's not helpful or constructive, but it is what it is: the question is considered on average not helpful.

My instinct is to remove a question altogether if is negative because it is considered to be not helpful, but I have learned from experience that people get irritated when I do that.

So what is the appropriate response?

- Interpret question and answer point values as being absolutely *meaningless* and pay absolutely no attention whatsoever to any point values?
- Or, interpret the point values has having meaning, and remove a question considered unhelpful by virtue of its question ranking and thus make the SO bank that much cleaner?

Comment: You can't remove question with upvoted answer...

Comment: Ok. Ignore all point values absolutely it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the question itself seems to me like it's alright, deleting it would be an *overreaction*.  You also can't since there's an upvoted answer on it, anyway.

That said, your two options speak of extremes.  Be careful with that since the truth lies somewhere in between.  You shouldn't consider your question worthless because ***one*** person didn't like it.

I wouldn't worry too much about this one, but take your time to go over the question and clean up some of the grammar and/or word structure.  Getting rid of unnecessary formatting like the bold may help as well.

Comment: On the surface it may look like an overreaction, but it is a building frustration from not being able to get a stable grasp of many unspoken assumptions. I stick to the facts and then I haven't provided context. I add context, then I wrote too much. This was why I wrote in absolutes, because when using SO I still experience frustration.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge:  It still reads like an overreaction to me.  Again, there's only one vote that's downvoted you, and I maintain that your question does look fairly complete, comprehensive, and on-topic.  It's a shame I don't do C# or I'd look into answering it myself.  Yes, I know that Stack Overflow is...[complicated...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309135/1079354), but don't let that get you down.  Maybe a brief break away from the computer would help you clear your head.

Comment: Agreed. Walking away.