# No Strunk & White - possible bug?

Tags: bug, badges

I noticed that I do not have [this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), and on my profile it still shows I made 1482 useful post edits.

Is it a possible bug or is there a misunderstanding in criteria?

Comment: You have it on [main](http://stackoverflow.com/users/260990/jigar-joshi?tab=badges) but not on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/260990/jigar-joshi?tab=badges) - they're awarded separately.

Comment: Related [Fluctuating badge counts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300067/why-does-my-badge-count-fluctuate)

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes?!

Answer (score 2):

As you can read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272450/6700857), your badges on Stack Overflow and Meta are different.